Who was this scientist who saw his whole theory(ies) demolished by a publication
I once read somewhere that, in the beginning of the XXth century -if I'm not mistaken- a scientist saw his whole assumptions or theory utterly refuted by the publication of a book by a mathematician... I don't remember exactly if the first one was a mathematician too, or a physicist, but it resulted in him realising his whole work was worth nothing and he later gave up doing his research.
My memories are pretty vague about this story: can someone tell me what I'm referring to, if possible ? Does this story ring a bell ?
Thanks.
Seb

You could be thinking of the mathematician Frege. His logicist programme was destroyed by Russell's Paradox. See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logicism.

And Rusell's project was demolished by Gödel's

The statement in the previous comment is not true. What Godel's results demolished was "Hilbert's program".

@AlexandreEremenko I would say both

@Mauricio I would say that Russel and Whitehead approach still holds, though it lost its popularity.
